# Orchard CMS installation shows setup page without styling

Tags: orchardcms

I have just installed Orchard CMS for the first time using first the manual option and then the Web Platform Installer option. Both options left me with this ugly screen:

[image: an unstyled setup screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So anyway, it turns out that the application pool was set to .Net Framework 4.0 CLASSIC mode. I changed it to Integrated Mode, and now everything is pretty:

[image]